# How to manage free ports with Ansible on Remote Server?

Tags: docker, ansible, port

Is there a possibility to manage free ports on a server with Ansible?

I have the following scenario:

- We have a few servers which will be setup with a base Ansible configuration.
- After that, we want to install different apps (by using `docker-compose`) which have to be bound to available ports on a machine.

The problem is now,

- that I do not know in advance which ports have already been used for different apps on the same machine.
- And the second problem is that I cannot just look for free ports because it is possible, that not all of the docker containers are running.

Has anyone a solution for this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: `And the second problem is that I cannot just look for free ports because it is possible, that not all of the docker containers are running`. => how and where are you storing the reserved ports for the services which are installed but not currently running on the host ?

Comment: There is no central storage planned at the moment. The question is, if I can just increment a value on a given server?

Comment: How are you going to know the incremented value is good to use if you cannot reliably check for free ports ?

Comment: One thing I would try is keep track of the affected ports on the server in [local facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d). That would be read with `gather_facts` any time you connect and you can update the local facts file whenever you assign a new port.

Answer (score 0):

> ***How to manage free ports with Ansible on Remote Server?***

I understand that you like to use only free or available ports on your target systems during an installation process of another software.

The solution for your described Use Case would be [Adding custom facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts).

---

It is assumed that a port configuration, a port configured for usage within the Remote Node is a [fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) about that system.

> *Ansible facts are data related to your remote systems, including operating systems, **IP addresses**, attached filesystems, **and more**. You can access this data in the `ansible_facts` variable.*

Therefore, regarding

> ***There is no central storage planned at the moment.***

such is not necessary since one can use the Current Configuration, the `ansible_facts` about the Remote Node which they are aware by his own as a kind of Distributed Database and just gather 'em.

> ***We want to install different apps (by using `docker-compose`) which have to be bound to available ports on a machine.***

During the process one just need to drop additional [local facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#facts-d-or-local-facts) on the target.

> ***I do not know in advance which ports have already been used for different apps on the same machine. And the second problem is that I cannot just look for free ports because it is possible, that not all of the docker containers are running.***

Gathering facts as in

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.ansible_local }}"
```

would then provide the necessary information, the ports in use.

---

**A step-by-step example**

about

- [How to implement and use a Custom Fact?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75212162/6771046)