# Redis Cluster: How to get the number of slots of a particular master node?

Tags: regex, redis, ansible, regex-group, redis-cluster

How to catch, ONLY the total number of slots an specific master node has in Ansible?

I know that if you run:

```
redis-cli --cluster check
```

You'll get this output for example:

```
192.168.56.115:6379 (7d0fb9ab...) -> 0 keys | 4242 slots | 0 slaves.
192.168.56.116:6379 (9fe57cd1...) -> 0 keys | 3950 slots | 0 slaves.
192.168.56.117:6379 (d37e89a6...) -> 0 keys | 4096 slots | 0 slaves.
192.168.56.118:6379 (e0eb74db...) -> 0 keys | 4096 slots | 0 slaves.
[OK] 0 keys in 4 masters.
0.00 keys per slot on average.
>>> Performing Cluster Check (using node 192.168.56.115:6379)
M: 7d0fb9abd91d6397f11e6f606c8ecf919ba2d1fe 192.168.56.115:6379
   slots:[0-4241] (4242 slots) master
M: 9fe57cd1faaa6e77d0e89c504b9f8b69f72c52aa 192.168.56.116:6379
   slots:[4242-8191] (3950 slots) master
M: d37e89a685ec31f3ce85544203132f862d8330a7 192.168.56.117:6379
   slots:[8192-12287] (4096 slots) master
M: e0eb74db5c6ccbc469538d05bf98302d056c7e05 192.168.56.118:6379
   slots:[12288-16383] (4096 slots) master
[OK] All nodes agree about slots configuration.
>>> Check for open slots...
>>> Check slots coverage...
[OK] All 16384 slots covered.
```

I want to write an Ansible playbook that given the target node's ip as `target_node_ip`, it gives this output: for example for `target_node_ip = 192.168.56.116`

```
3950
```

I've tried many regex patterns, but they didn't help me.

For example, I wrote these tasks:

```
- name: Catch --cluster check
  command: >
    redis-cli --user default --cluster check 192.168.56.115:6379
  register: cluster_check_output

- name: Catch the number of slots the target currently has
  set_fact:
    node_slots: "{{cluster_check_output.stdout | regex_replace('.*{{ target_node_ip }}:6379 \\(.{8}\\.{3}\\) -> \\d+ keys | (\\d+) slots | \\d+ slaves.*', '\\1')}}"

- name: Debug node_slots
  debug:
    var: node_slots
```

And the output is this:

```
TASK [Debug node_slots] ***********************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/behnia/projects/redis-test/redis-cluster/redis-cluster-management/playbooks/remove_node.yml:64
ok: [server3] => {
    "node_slots": "192.168.56.115:6379 (7d0fb9ab...) -> 0 keys |4242|\n192.168.56.116:6379 (9fe57cd1...) -> 0 keys |3950|\n192.168.56.117:6379 (d37e89a6...) -> 0 keys |4096|\n192.168.56.118:6379 (e0eb74db...) -> 0 keys |4096|\n\u001b[32;1m[OK] 0 keys in 4 masters.\n\u001b[0m0.00 keys per slot on average.\n\u001b[29;1m>>> Performing Cluster Check (using node 192.168.56.115:6379)\n\u001b[0mM: 7d0fb9abd91d6397f11e6f606c8ecf919ba2d1fe 192.168.56.115:6379\n   slots:[0-4241] (4242 slots) master\nM: 9fe57cd1faaa6e77d0e89c504b9f8b69f72c52aa 192.168.56.116:6379\n   slots:[4242-8191] (3950 slots) master\nM: d37e89a685ec31f3ce85544203132f862d8330a7 192.168.56.117:6379\n   slots:[8192-12287] (4096 slots) master\nM: e0eb74db5c6ccbc469538d05bf98302d056c7e05 192.168.56.118:6379\n   slots:[12288-16383] (4096 slots) master\n\u001b[32;1m[OK] All nodes agree about slots configuration.\n\u001b[0m\u001b[29;1m>>> Check for open slots...\n\u001b[0m\u001b[29;1m>>> Check slots coverage...\n\u001b[0m\u001b[32;1m[OK] All16384covered.\n\u001b[0m"
}
```

If you see, instead of replacing the whole output with 3950, **it replaced every `| <#> slots |` with `|#|`, where # is number of slots (in this context `4242, 3950, 4096, 4096`)**.

What I want is just **3950** (for `target_node_ip = 192.168.56.116`)

Comment: Wouldn't be using and / or enhancing the [`redis` module – Various redis commands, replica and flush](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/redis_module.html) a better and general approach? https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/redis.py

Comment: I'll definitely try that out too.
But the thing is, I want to learn how to catch a part of a string in ansible.
Because I know I'll need it somewhere else.

Comment: If you are going to use `command` or `shell` anyway, a quick and simple option would be pre-processing, in example via `redis-cli --cluster check | grep {{ target_node_ip }} | head -n 1"`, then `| cut -d '|' -f 2 | grep -o '[0-9]' | tr -d '\n'`, ending up with `redis-cli --cluster check | grep {{ target_node_ip }} | head -n 1 | cut -d '|' -f 2 | grep -o '[0-9]' | tr -d '\n'` and register only that final result (number).

Comment: "_I want to learn how to catch a part of a string in Ansible._", in your specific Use Case and because of Distributed Computing, I recommend to do pre-processing. Either via the Shell example, Custom Facts or a specific Module. What you try to do is currently How Ansible should not be used. [Think declaratively: Ansible is a Desired State Engine by design. If you’re trying to “write code” in your plays and roles, you’re setting yourself up for failure. Our YAML-based playbooks were never meant to be for programming.](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-best-practices-essentials)

Comment: You could also try to [Parse semi-structured text with Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/cli_parsing.html) by using [`cli_parse` module – Parse cli output or text using a variety of parsers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/cli_parse_module.html), see [Linux example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/cli_parsing.html#linux-example).

Comment: I've just seen that there is also an option [`redis-cli --csv`](https://redis.io/docs/connect/cli/) for CSV output, as well Lua scripts ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned within the comments one minimal example playbook ...

**Pre-processing in `shell`**

on Remote Node(s) and in order to catch up the final result set only.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    target_node_ip: 192.168.56.116

  tasks:

  - name: Catch --cluster check
    shell: |
      cat redis.stdout |           # redis-cli --cluster check
      grep {{ target_node_ip }} |  # for specific node only
      head -n 1 |                  # first line found
      cut -d '|' -f 2 |            # result between pipes
      grep -o '[0-9]' |            # and numbers only
      tr -d '\n'                   #
    register: slots

  - name: Show the number of slots the target currently has
    debug:
      var: slots.stdout
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show the number of slots the target currently has] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  slots.stdout: '3950'
```

**Ansible Custom Fact**

Somehow similar can be implemented as a [Custom fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#facts-d-or-local-facts). Then just `gather_facts` or `setup` would be necessary. See [How to implement and use a Custom Fact?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75212162/6771046)

Comment: Thanks for your answer & also for your help on showing me other good alternatives , as a best practice for Ansible!